# Compile timescaledb source code on debian10 arm64

Tags: postgresql, debian, timescaledb

I have debian10 installed on my raspberry PI 4,and I have installed PostgreSql 12.4,Since ARM64 does not have an installation package for timescaledb, I wanted to install timescaledb by compiling the source code.Now we have some problems。
1,clone code from github

```
1, git clone https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb.git
```

```
2,cd timescaledb
```

```
3,./bootstrap -DUSE_OPENSSL=0 -DREGRESS_CHECKS=OFF -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON`
```

Error is as follows

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:334 (message):
  Could not find pg_config.h in /usr/include/postgresql.  Make sure PG_PATH
  points to a valid PostgreSQL installation that includes development
  headers.
```

I don't know how to solve this problem now

Comment: Like the error message says - do you have the postgresql development headers installed? Usually from a package called "postgresql-...-dev"

Comment: @RichardHuxton Thank you, I installed not the development version, I will try again after reinstallation

Answer (score 5):

You to need install the development package.
i.e postgreSql 13:

```
apt install postgresql-server-dev-13
```